# DB2 varchar characters casE?

Tags: sql, db2, case, varchar

firstly sorry for the ambiguous title I couldn't think of a proper title, but anyway I have a column titled `unit_id` it is a varchar. and some of the data comes in with 3 characters, but i need them to have a 0 in front of the values.
I was thinking of doing a `case or if` but im not sure how to write it.
RECAP
data comes in as `164`, but I would like it to come in as `0164`
thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [LPAD function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_lpad.dita):

```
SELECT LPAD(unit_id,4,'0') FROM your_table
```